# How to rewrite integral of Brownian motion $\int^1_0 \left( W(r)-\int_0^1W(s)ds\right)^2dr$

Tags: integration, statistics, brownian-motion

How would I go to rewrite

$$\int^1_0 \left(  W(r)-\int_0^1W(s)ds\right)^2dr$$

into 
$$\int_0^1 W(r)^2dr -\left( \int_0^1W(r)dr \right)^2$$

where $W(r)$ is a standard Brownian Motion.

Comment: There should be a square in the first line integral, right?

Comment: oh yes you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note,

$$\begin{align}
& \int^1_0 \left(  W(r)-\int_0^1W(s)ds\right)^2dr \\
& =\int^1_0 \left(  W^2(r)-2W(r)\int_0^1W(s)ds+\left( \int_0^1W(s)ds \right)^2\right)dr \\
& =\int^1_0 W^2(r)dr-2\int^1_0 W(r)dr \int_0^1W(s)ds+\int^1_0 dr\left( \int_0^1 W(s)ds \right)^2 \\
& =\int^1_0 W^2(r)dr-2\left( \int_0^1 W(r)dr \right)^2+ \left( \int_0^1 W(s)ds \right)^2 \\
& =\int_0^1 W(r)^2dr -\left( \int_0^1W(r)dr \right)^2 \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: It's nothing to do with Brownian motion, really, the same would be true of any reasonable function on $[0,1]$. It's the same proof as $E[(X-E[X])^2] = E[X^2]-E[X]^2$ for random variables.